# Verifying PayPal Mobile Payment - What to do with this verification

Tags: cocoa-touch, paypal

I'm using PayPal's new iOS SDK for a mobile app I'm doing. When a payment is processed, a verification of type: Adaptive Payments (when the user pays with PayPal) and
REST APIs (when the user pays with a credit card) are processed. My question is what am I suppose to do with these verifications. I've read their documentation but it isn't all that clear, obviously verifying helps with fraud, but I'm confused on the steps that are needed to handle these verifications. Do I send it to my server(php), if so what is my server suppose to do with it? Should I save these in the db? I'm new to PayPal if anyone could give some advice, I'd appreciate it thanks.

Example of Verification:

```
{
"proof_of_payment": {
"adaptive_payment": {
  "pay_key": "AP-70M68096ML426802W",
  "payment_exec_status": "COMPLETED",
  "timestamp": "2013-02-20T00:26:25Z",
  "app_id": "APP-91B933855X481767M"
}
},
"payment": {
"short_description": "Hipster t-shirt",
"amount": "9.95",
"currency_code": "USD"
},
"client": {
"platform": "iOS",
"paypal_sdk_version": "1.0.0",
"environment": "live",
"product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send them to your server.

Your server (which you trust) should communicate directly with PayPal to verify that the proof of payments are valid. The [documentation on verifying proofs of payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) has details on what API calls you can make for verification. If you have specific questions about them, you should ask those separately, with details. The reason to verify them is that, if you don't, someone could give you a *fake* proof of payment and you wouldn't know it.

You probably want to save them in the db (or at the very least important chunks of them like the `pay_key` or `payment_id`).