# Paypal payments verify

Tags: paypal, sdk, payment, verify, proof

Hello and sorry for my english...

I have implemented Paypal sdk for android, it works fine! But maybe for my english I don´t understand what i have to do here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

               // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                // for more details.

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ha ocurrido un error, inténtelo de nuevo en unos instantes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                IrActivityAnterior();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have read about it but I don´t know if I need to send a proof of payment to the person who has bought my app or if I only need to get this proof and save it. And the other question is how can I verify it? What steps I need to follow??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) in the example, you'll see that the purpose of verification is for *you* to verify that the payment succeeded.  Another question of the same nature was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992819/verifying-paypal-mobile-payment-what-to-do-with-this-verification?rq=1).

Comment: Ok, but where I tipe this code?? In php? And how can I do the call?

curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails \

-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: user_id" \

-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: password" \

-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: signature" \

-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \

-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \

-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-91B933855X481767M" \

-d "payKey=AP-70M68096ML426802W&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US"

Thank you again